# How to use multiple auths/ logins for same docker registry

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm using latest gitlab and the integrated docker registry. For each project I create an individual deploy token. On the host where I want to deploy the images I do `docker login https://registry.example.com/project1`, enter the deploy token and get success. Pulling the image just works fine.

On the *same* host I need to deploy another image from the same registry. So I do `docker login https://registry.example.com/project2`, the the deploy token (which is differrent to token 1, because each project has its own deploy tokens) and get success.

However looking in the `.docker/config.json` I can see docker just stores the domain, not the full url, and so replaces the old auth token with the new one. So I can only pull image 2 now, but not image 1 anymore.

Is this a bug in docker? How to use more than one auth/ deploy token for the same registry?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: @CharlesMorin See my answer

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use the [`--config`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files) option of the Docker client to store multiple credentials into different paths:

```
docker --config ~/.project1 login registry.example.com -u <username> -p <deploy_token>
docker --config ~/.project2 login registry.example.com -u <username> -p <deploy_token>
```

Then you are able to call Docker commands by *selecting* your credential:

```
docker --config ~/.project1 pull registry.example.com/project1
docker --config ~/.project2 pull registry.example.com/project2
```

Comment: Any way to get this working when deploying a swarm stack?

Comment: help me too even if docker returns : ```WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.```. It should be better to define read only token !

Comment: Sadly this seems to be no longer relevant when using a credential store. Each config file is just `{"auths": {"registry.gitlab.com": {}}, "credsStore": "pass" }`

Answer (score 14):

Currently it's not possible. See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37569.

However, one *workaround*, in case it serves you, is to store credentials in a CWD-dependant directory:

```
export DOCKER_CONFIG=.docker
cd your-docker-project
docker login registry.example.com
docker-compose pull

cd ../other project
# repeat steps here
```

This way, by changing directory, you change credentials. You have to `cd` to use git and docker-compose anyways.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try!

Comment: By performing these operations in a script file, you can use the `DOCKER_CONFIG` variable within a specific scope, without worrying about global pollution.

Comment: Use `export DOCKER_CONFIG="${HOME}/.docker/another_profile"` to avoid creating `.docker` folder in CWD

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and my workaround for now is to use a dedicated user / token:

1. Create a new User
2. Add the user to all the projects you need with role `Reporter`
3. Create a new `Personal Access Token` with scope `read_registry`

You can now login using the newly created token and pull:

`docker login https://registry.example.com -u REPORTER_USER -p PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN`

This should do the trick, you can create a token with an existing user too

Answer (score 2):

The contents of my compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:

    test1:
        image: <mygitlabregistryurl>/project1
        deploy:
            replicas: 1

    test2:
        image: <mygitlabregistryurl>/project2
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
```

There are 2 ways to solve.

- You can `login` with the following command, but then you must make the service updates together with `CI`.

  ```
  docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  ```
- For the authorized user in the project, you can create a personal access token with the permission of read_registry and use the following command.

  ```
  docker login -u <username> -p <access_token> $CI_REGISTRY
  ```

Gitlab docs here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#authenticating-to-the-container-registry